# XO game using c# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm new to C# (and programming at all) and i'm trying to write an 'XO' game along with ASP.NET
i'm getting a problem after the first player clicks a button.

turns doesn't switch and any click after the 1st does nothing.  what is wrong with my code ?

```
public partial class GamePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Player player1 = new Player();
    Player player2 = new Player();
    int turn;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.turn = 0;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }

        if (turn == 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = (Session["player1"] as Player).getname();
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = (Session["player2"] as Player).getname();
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["p1"] = player1;
        Session["p2"] = player2;
        player1.setsymbol("X");
        player2.setsymbol("O");

        if (Button1.Text == "")
        {
            if (turn == 0)
            {
                Button1.Text = player1.getsymbol();
                Label1.Text = (Session["player2"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Button1.Text = player2.getsymbol();
                Label1.Text = (Session["player1"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button2.Text == "")
        {
            if (turn == 0)
            {
                Button2.Text = player1.getsymbol();
                Label1.Text = (Session["player2"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Button2.Text = player2.getsymbol();
                Label1.Text = (Session["player1"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button3.Text == "")
        {
            if (turn == 0)
            {
                Button3.Text = player1.getsymbol();
                Label1.Text = (Session["player2"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Button3.Text = player2.getsymbol();
                Label1.Text = (Session["player1"] as Player).getname();
                turn = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

// this is an example - i have the same lines from button1 to 9

Comment: on page load each time u r setting turn=0, that might be issue?

Comment: You have "logical" issue on the path of your program, that you need to step by step debugging it and solve it.

Comment: im setting turn = 0 on every page load cause i want every game to start with player1 (X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime page renders, you set `turn` to 0 in `Page_Load`. Because `Page_Load` is executed upon every page load, you won't get any other value and this is probably the major issue here.

To properly support the lifetime of such variables that should keep value upon consecutive requests, wrap them in simple property:

```
public int turn
{
    get
    {
        if ( Session["turn"] != null )
             return (int)Session["turn"];
        return 0; // default value if not set before
    }
    set
    {
        Session["turn"] = value;
    }
}
```

This way everytime you refer to `turn` in your code, setting it to 0 or 1 or **comparing** the value to 0 or 1, you will refer to the same value, possibly stored during previous request(s).

Comment: yes its working, thank you !! can you tell me what is the difference between this solution to just put "this.turn = 0;" inside the if (!ispostback) ?? (when i did it , i got the whole table filled just whit X's like the value is always = 0)

Comment: Just think of the page load code executing **everytime** you hit the button. From the server perspective every request is a new, fresh one. If you don't do anyhting to retain state (like Session), statefull code won't work.

Comment: yes, a friend just told me the exact thing.  thank you Wiktor !

Answer (score 0):

`this.turn=0;` should be executed only when `IsPostBack` is false. Move this line inside `if` in your `Page_Load`.

Comment: its not working .. as i said - the first click does work , i get an x on the button and the player name changes to the second one. and thats where it stops